# Application communication with HTML page

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a chat socket server client C# application.

When the client write the massage "@game" the server send to the client the files of the javascript game (html file, javascript file and bunch of pictures), the client saves the game in C directory in folder the client create and open the game in browser.

This project is a school assignment, so I was asked when the client ending to play the game the client need to delete the files from the C directory.
I am very limited on what I can use because this is a school assignment.

I need to think of a way that the client C# application will know that the person have finished to play the game, the html page is not connected to the internet and I need to leave it at this way, I can't turn the html page into aspx page, maybe some code in js will do the trick.

Comment: Spawn the browser process from your C# application and monitor its state. When the process stops running you can delete the files.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
using (Process browserProcess = new Process())
{
    browserProcess.StartInfo = 
        new ProcessStartInfo("firefox.exe", "file:///C:/pathToIndex.html");
    browserProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    browserProcess.Start();

    browserProcess.Exited += (s, e) =>
    {
        // delete files
    };

    // do something that blocks execution
}
```